# How to fix the dimensions of a shadowbox?

Tags: enumerate, box

I'm a beginner in LaTeX and I would like to know how to fix the dimensions of a shadowbox used to frame the numbers of an enumerate environment. Indeed, I would like all the boxes in the example below to have the same dimensions (those of the first one) and we see that when we have a 4 or a number superior to 10, dimensions change and I would like them to remain the same as the one framing the 1.
Here is my code :

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fancybox}
\setlength{\shadowsize}{2.5pt}
\newcommand{\shadbox}[1]{\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\protect\shadowbox{\hskip0.3em\itshape\bfseries#1\hskip 0.3em}}}

\begin{document} 
\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\shadbox{\arabic*},leftmargin=1.1em]
   \item    
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I've changed the command that it not only uses the width, but also the height and depth of the optional argument.

I've changed your `\shadbox` command to take an optional argument. If you use the optional argument the width will be the one of the optional argument, without an optional argument it will have natural width:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\shadowsize}{2.5pt}
\newsavebox\shadboxA
\newsavebox\shadboxB
\newcommand{\shadbox}[2][]
  {%
    \raisebox{-0.3\height}
      {%
        \shadowbox
          {%
            \hskip0.3em
            \itshape\bfseries
            \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
              #2%
            \else
              \sbox\shadboxA{#1}%
              \sbox\shadboxB{\makebox[\wd\shadboxA][c]{#2}}%
              \ht\shadboxB=\ht\shadboxA
              \dp\shadboxB=\dp\shadboxA
              \usebox\shadboxB
            \fi
            \hskip 0.3em
          }%
      }%
  }

\begin{document} 
\begin{enumerate}[label={\protect\shadbox[0]{\clap{\arabic*}}},leftmargin=1.1em]
   \item a
   \item a
   \item a
   \item a
   \item a
   \item a
   \item a
   \item a
   \item a
   \item a
   \item a
   \item a
   \item a
   \item a
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you have (if there is one) solution to decrease the height of the boxes where there is a 4 or a 7 which are a little higher than the others?